# Set environment variable through process.env for entire script

Tags: node.js, bash

I want to do something like what [`cross-env-shell`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env#cross-env-vs-cross-env-shell) does. I have a npm script like `node createAccounts.js & (sleep 5 && npm start)`. In `createAccounts.js`, I set some environment variables via `process.env`. But these environment variables cannot be seen via the next process `npm start`. What can I do to retain the environment variables across commands?

Comment: Create a common js/json config file. Update it in the first script and read in the second.

Comment: @alexmac that's what I'm doing now but I need to eventually set the environment variables as another dependency uses them.